# SQL report to display data in matrix, from row based data

Tags: sql

I have a data set that is beyond my experience to build a specific report using sql, so I'm looking for guidance in the right direction.

Data

```
+-----+--------+------------+-----------------+
| ID  |  Name  | QuestionID | Question Answer |
+-----+--------+------------+-----------------+
| 100 | Ethan  |          3 | Null            |
| 100 | Ethan  |          4 | 4 p.m.          |
| 100 | Ethan  |          5 | no              |
| 101 | Samuel |          3 | Null            |
| 101 | Samuel |          4 | Null            |
| 101 | Samuel |          5 | 10 a.m.         |
| 103 | Faris  |          3 | yes             |
| 103 | faris  |          5 | 8 a.m.          |
+-----+--------+------------+-----------------+
```

I need to build the output into a matrix that lists each ID once and pivots the questions and answers into columns vs rows.

```
+-----+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+
| ID  |  Name  | Question3 | Answer3 | Question4 | Answer4 | Question5 | Answer5 |
+-----+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+
| 100 | Ethan  |         3 | Null    |         4 | 4 p.m.  |         5 | no      |
| 101 | Samuel |         3 | Null    |         4 | Null    |         5 | 10 a.m. |
| 103 | Faris  |         3 | yes     |           |         |         5 | 8 a.m.  |
+-----+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+
```

The other part of this is the # of questions can change if the user adds or archives a question.

I've simplified the data, question ID is a reference to a separate table that houses the actual question.

Comment: Which database?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: @Sentinel, MS SQL 13.0.x

Comment: @klutt, I have not had to use a pivot before, most of my experience is on the php \ tlist_sql side. I would ordinarily use a for statement to loop through each and pull the data by ID, and not do it on the sql side. However this will ultimately end up in infomaker, and not in a way I'm overly familiar with, open to suggestions for resources to lookup \ review to increase my skillset.

Comment: Thing is, SO is not a code writing service. If you have not even tried, you should not post a question. This is somewhat basic sql, you you should read som sql tutorials.

Comment: You could google t-sql pivot, Microsoft will supply the syntax, and you can try it on your data.

Comment: @Sentinel & klutt, my apologizes if I presented my question poorly. I've not used pivot before, and I couldn't find reference to applying pivot to a subset of data so I was unsure if that was the best place to start. I also have seen some of the "do my work for me" posts on SO, and I was trying to avoid that. I just didn't know if I was even going the right way, so I was looking for direction. I'll continue to google, and look elsewhere if I'm still stumped. 

Thanks for your input.